# Files associations (MIME) in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, mime-type, file-association

I'm trying to figure out how files associations work in Ubuntu 18.04.

I looked around the web (quite a lot actually) and found these files:

- [`A`] `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`
- [`B`] `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`
- [`C`] `~/.config/mimeapps.list`
- [`D`] `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

One of the most informative pages I found is [ArchLinux XDG MIME Applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications).

`A` and `B` have the same content on a fresh install but there isn't a symbolic link from one to the other. I understand that `A` is for Gnome desktop and `B` is the distribution override.

So my question is about the user override:

- [Gnome documentation](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-application-user.html.en) says that `D` is the user override
- [ArchLinux XDG MIME Applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications) says that `D` is deprecated
- `D` doesn't exist anymore in 18.04 (I think it did in Ubuntu 16.04), only `C`

I'm then asking:

1. Which one should I use between `C` and `D`?
2. Bonus: What's the history of these files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your list is extensive. If however your want to look extensively for all possible list try:  sudo grep --include *.list -rnw '/.' -e "extension_looking_for" This is going to take quite some time but will deliver all possible lists

Comment: correction - I meant exhaustive